# C, clock_gettime, returned incorrect nanosecond value?

Tags: c, timer, posix, gettime

I'm writing a simple program, which checks if elapsed time is more than 1 seconds. I take start time with a clock_gettime(), then I call sleep(5), take new time and I check if the difference is bigger than 1; I sleep 5 seconds, then it should be greater than 5, but my program prints a strange result.

this is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    struct timespec tv1,tv3,expected;
    struct timespec nano1;

    tv1.tv_nsec = 0;
    tv3.tv_nsec = 0;

    expected.tv_nsec = 400000;

    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tv3) == -1){
        perror(NULL);
    }

    sleep(5);

    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&tv1) == -1){
        perror(NULL);
    }


    long nsec = tv1.tv_nsec - tv3.tv_nsec;

    if(nsec>expected.tv_nsec){
        printf("nsec runned: %ld   nsec timeout: %ld\n",nsec,expected.tv_nsec);
    }


    printf("elapsed nanoseconds: %ld\n",nsec);


    if((nsec>expected.tv_nsec))
        printf("expired timer\n");

    else
        printf("not expired timer\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output of my program is:

"elapsed nanoseconds: 145130" and "not expired timeout"

Where is the problem?

Comment: You forget to account for the *seconds* that have passed! Five seconds and ten nanoseconds will with your calculations only be a difference of the ten nanoseconds, the five seconds you don't care about.

Answer (score 5):

The time represented in a `struct timespec` has two components:

- `tv_sec` — a `time_t` value for the integer number of seconds.
- `tv_nsec` — a 32-bit integer for the number of nanoseconds, 0..999,999,999

Your calculation didn't take into account the difference between the `tv_sec` values.  It is somewhat surprising that the difference between the nanosecond values was as large as you say, but far from impossible.  To get the whole difference, you need to take into account both the `tv_sec` and the `tv_nsec` components.

#### `sub_timespec()`

You can subtract two values (to get the difference) using a function like:

```
enum { NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000 };

void sub_timespec(struct timespec t1, struct timespec t2, struct timespec *td)
{
    td->tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec;
    td->tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_sec > 0 && td->tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
    else if (td->tv_sec < 0 && td->tv_nsec > 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
}
```

#### `fmt_timespec`

You can format it as a floating-point value with the specified number of decimal places using a function like this:

```
int fmt_timespec(const struct timespec *value, int dp, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    assert(value != 0 && buffer != 0 && buflen != 0);
    if (value == 0 || buffer == 0 || buflen == 0)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    assert(dp >= 0 && dp <= 9);
    if (dp < 0 || dp > 9)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if ((value->tv_sec > 0 && value->tv_nsec < 0) ||
        (value->tv_sec < 0 && value->tv_nsec > 0))
    {
        /* Non-zero components of struct timespec must have same sign */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    int len;
    if (dp == 0)
        len = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%ld", value->tv_sec);
    else
    {
        long nsec = value->tv_nsec;
        long secs = value->tv_sec;
        const char *sign = (secs < 0 || (secs == 0 && nsec < 0)) ? "-" : "";
        if (secs < 0)
            secs = -secs;
        if (nsec < 0)
            nsec = -nsec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9 - dp; i++)
            nsec /= 10;
        len = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "%s%ld.%.*ld", sign, secs, dp, nsec);
    }
    if (len > 0 && (size_t)len < buflen)
        return len;
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
}
```

---

#### Revised version of code in question

The header `time_io.h` declares the format and scanning functions for `struct timespec`; the `time_math.h` header declares the functions for adding and subtracting `struct timespec` values.  It is probably over-compartmenting the code to have that many headers.

```
#include "time_io.h"
#include "time_math.h"
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { NS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000 };

int main(void)
{
    struct timespec tv3;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tv3) == -1)
        perror("clock_gettime()");

    sleep(5);

    struct timespec tv1;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tv1) == -1)
        perror("clock_gettime()");

    struct timespec td;
    sub_timespec(tv3, tv1, &td);

    int64_t ts_in_ns = td.tv_sec * NS_PER_SECOND + td.tv_nsec;

    char buffer[32];
    fmt_timespec(&td, 9, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    printf("Elapsed time: %s (%" PRId64 " nanoseconds)\n", buffer, ts_in_ns);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
Elapsed time: 5.005192000 (5005192000 nanoseconds)
```

On a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 (which finally has `clock_gettime()` — earlier versions of Mac OS X did not support it), the resolution of `clock_gettime()` is 1000 nanoseconds, effectively microseconds.  So, the last 3 decimal places are always zeros on a Mac.

#### `add_timespec()`

For completeness, you can add two `struct timespec` values with:

```
void add_timespec(struct timespec t1, struct timespec t2, struct timespec *td)
{
    td->tv_nsec = t2.tv_nsec + t1.tv_nsec;
    td->tv_sec  = t2.tv_sec + t1.tv_sec;
    if (td->tv_nsec >= NS_PER_SECOND)
    {
        td->tv_nsec -= NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec++;
    }
    else if (td->tv_nsec <= -NS_PER_SECOND)
    {
        td->tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }
}
```

#### `scn_timespec()`

And the 'scanning' process is messier (input often is messier than output):

```
int scn_timespec(const char *str, struct timespec *value)
{
    assert(str != 0 && value != 0);
    if (str == 0 || value == 0)
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    long sec;
    long nsec = 0;
    int sign = +1;
    char *end;
    /* No library routine sets errno to 0 - but this one needs to */
    int old_errno = errno;

    errno = 0;

    /* Skip leading white space */
    while (isspace((unsigned char)*str))
        str++;

    /* Detect optional sign */
    if (*str == '+')
        str++;
    else if (*str == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        str++;
    }

    /* Next character must be a digit */
    if (!isdigit((unsigned char)*str))
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    /* Convert seconds part of string */
    sec = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    if (end == str || ((sec == LONG_MAX || sec == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE))
    {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (*end != '\0' && !isspace((unsigned char)*end))
    {
        if (*end++ != '.')
        {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
        if (*end == '\0')
            nsec = 0;
        else if (isdigit((unsigned char)*end))
        {
            char *frac = end;
            nsec = strtol(frac, &end, 10);
            if (end == str ||
                ((nsec == LONG_MAX || nsec == LONG_MIN) && errno == ERANGE) ||
                (nsec < 0 || nsec >= NS_PER_SECOND) || (end - frac > 9))
            {
                errno = EINVAL;
                return -1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 9 - (end - frac); i++)
                nsec *= 10;
        }
    }

    /* Allow trailing white space - only */
    unsigned char uc;
    while ((uc = (unsigned char)*end++) != '\0')
    {
        if (!isspace(uc))
        {
            errno = EINVAL;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    /* Success! */
    value->tv_sec = sec * sign;
    value->tv_nsec = nsec * sign;
    errno = old_errno;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!One more question: if i need only nanoseconds, is return value reliable?For example, if I want know if 30 nanoseconds elapsed, it could return an incorret result?

Comment: It depends on what you mean, but mostly 'no'.  You're not just interested in the nanoseconds; you're interested in both.  If you want to convert the time into nanoseconds, then you can use `struct timespec ts; sub_timespec(tv3, tv1, &ts); int64_t ts_in_ns = ts.tv_sec * NS_PER_SECOND + ts.tv_nsec;` and work with the `ts_in_ns` value.  You should be safe from overflow for a while (over 250 years, if I'm calculating correctly) assuming the current Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00).

Comment: `if (td->tv_sec > 0 && td->tv_nsec < 0)
    {
        td->tv_nsec += NS_PER_SECOND;
        td->tv_sec--;
    }` is unclear.  It seems to imply the `tv_nsec` should match in sign to `tv_sec`.  IMO, having that member end with a value in the `[0...+999999999]`, regardless of sign of `tn_sec`, matches the intent of `tv_nsec`  OTOH, I have not found a spec on that minimum normalized value of that field

Comment: @chux: You're right that there is an issue; consider it a design decision in the code.  There is no specification for negative time spec values — the systems do not generate such values.  You can do it either way, but it is easier for formatting if you don't have to adjust the value of `tv_sec` and convert `tv_nsec` to `NS_PER_SECOND - tv_nsec` before printing, etc.  You just have to fix signs.  (I'm taking liberties with notation but without being confusing, I hope).  Feel free to write the alternative implementation.

Comment: Curious, why the `/* Skip leading white space */ ...  /* Next character must be a digit */` code  and not get right into `strtol()`?  That earlier code is redundant with `strtol()` and misses bad syntax like "--123" and wrong answers with "-2147483648".  Hmmm, I see now you are trying to apply the sign to both members.  As you say "'scanning' process is messier"

Comment: @chux: "-2147483648" — only if you have a 32-bit `long` on a two's complement machine; not if you have a one's complement machine with 32-bit `long` (the portable range of `long` is officially ±2,147,483,647).  And, on the contrary to your claim, it does not accept double signs.  I want the sign separately from the value for the numbers at the end.  Yes, I could punt to `strtol()` and determine the sign from the value returned by `strtol()`.  I chose not to.  You may choose to do as you wish when you reimplement the code.  (And I see you edited your comment while I was preparing my response.)

Comment: @chux: Note that if I did not extract the sign, I'd get the wrong answer for `-0.123456789` (the negative would be lost).  That's a better reason than those in the previous comment.

Comment: The corner case I was thinking was with input `"-2147483648.0"`, code calls `strtol(`"2147483648...", ...)` which incorrectly overflows.  You are certainly correct, code does detect `"--123...."`.

Comment: @chux: Also, the same example (`-0.123456789`) is why I use the negative fractional part.  The alternative notation would use `tv_sec = -1` and `tv_nsec = 876543211` to represent `-0.123456789`. The "one billion's complement" number for the nanoseconds is a little peculiar (not insurmountably peculiar, but peculiar).  That negative notation is a lot harder to understand in the debugger than the 'both parts negative' notation.

Comment: A reasonable design choice (negative `tv_nsec)`.  The issue stems from using a `struct` meant for a time interval as one for a time difference.

Comment: @chux: yes — though there's an argument that a `struct timespec` is always a time interval, being the time interval from the Unix Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00).  But there's no specification of what should happen for times prior to the epoch.  _If only `strftime()` handled fractional seconds, and `mktime()` didn't return `-1` on error and for `1969-12-31 23:59:59 +00:00), and `strptime()` was part of standard C and supported fractional seconds._  Grumble, grumble.  This imposes one order on the system; there is an alternative order available if you prefer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152858/discussion-between-chux-and-jonathan-leffler).

Comment: @chux: I don't know if it matters, but POSIX.1 does explicitly specify the range for the `tv_nsec` field to be 0 to 999,999,999 (inclusive) [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_08_05).  All other values are simply *"invalid"* when supplied to the POSIX.1 time functions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the nsec (nanoseconds) portion of the timestamps and totally ignoring the sec (seconds) part.  Those timestamps are composed of two integers, and to get any meaning from them you need both.

Ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec

Comment: The seconds portion can be a 64-bit quantity.  It is on a Mac; probably on 64-bit Linux, too; and probably on most 64-bit Unix systems.

Comment: ok, maybe i don't understand how use this function; i thought that nanosecond value includes second value, for example 5 seconds will be 5000000000 nanoseconds..Does it work in this way?

Comment: No.  5 seconds would be represented as {5, 0}.  Five and a half would be {5, 500000000} and you'd interpret it as half a second.  It's in the link I posted: *"nanoseconds (valid values are [0, 999999999])"*.

Comment: @ClaudioSantoro: no; the whole seconds are in the `tv_sec` part; the subsecond part (only) is in `tv_nsec`.

Comment: However, my problem is that i have to implemented for University a simply version of UDP for reliable communication; then, i need a better precision than seconds; if i only use nanoseconds, could i have problems?Should i use another function?

Comment: When a  human being says "five and a half seconds," do you understand what they mean?  You don't think they mean "half a second."  This is just like that.  A whole part and a fractional part.